# Run Javascript unload to run calculation

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that will run a JS calculation when the value in input "cage_linear_feet" is changed and this works fine.

How do I run this on page load when there is a value already in the input?

See my code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function updatesum() {
document.form.cage_estimate.value = (document.form.cage_linear_feet.value) * 100;
};

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="form" action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

<input type="text" name="cage_linear_feet" id="cage_linear_feet" value="10" onchange="updatesum()">

<br>

<input type="text" class="estimate" name="cage_estimate" id="cage_estimate" disabled>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

John

Comment: Add `window.onload = function(){
 updatesum();
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onload = function(){
  // code to call on load
}
```

Comment: Do I just wrap that around the code I posted above? I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: `window.onload = function () { updatesum() }` below the first function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this. It'll run updatesum() if a numerical value is present on page load.

```
/*On page load */
$(document).ready(function()
{
    /* Retrieve value */
    val = document.form.cage_linear_feet.value;
    /*Run updatesum() if the val is numeric */
    if(!isNaN(parseFloat(val)) && isFinite(val);)
        updatesum();
});
```

Comment: I'd bet that's because you're not using jQuery. =). But in all fairness, Vanilla JS is fine.

Comment: I got it working by taking out the if(!isNaN.... line. How do I format the result in the input so it's 00,000.00?